# align text before a radio button

Tags: css, angular-material

Bare with me guys , I am just new to css, hope you will understand. I have a concern. how do we align the text that it should be before the radio buttons

So it would look like this ---> Include Completed and Cancelled? [radio-button yes option] [radio-button No option] cause currently my radio buttons are below the text. Any idea ? Thanks.

It should look something like this..
`Include Completed and Cancelled? O YES O NO`

#screenshot , current output

[image]

#code

```
<div style="padding-top: 18px;">
        <p>Include Completed and Cancelled?</p>
        <mat-radio-group name="subtenantGuaranty"  layout="column" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: center;gap: 30px;">
          <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of completedOrCanceled" class="md-primary" [value]="option.text" color="primary">
            {{ option.text }}
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```html
<div style="padding-top: 18px;">
    <mat-radio-group name="subtenantGuaranty"  layout="column" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: center;gap: 30px;">
        <p>Include Completed and Cancelled?</p>
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of completedOrCanceled" class="md-primary" [value]="option.text" color="primary">
            {{ option.text }}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```